# Asp.net identity authentication in wcf service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-identity

I've created a website which stores some user-created content. 
I watt to expose this content through a wcf service. 
On My site I use asp.net identity to handle membership, authentication and autorization. I want to do the same with my service. 
I've looked All over the internet regarding this matter, but can't seem to find any information.

So far I've managed to set up a custom user name password validator, which programmatically uses the identity framework. This seem like something test should've been built into the framework Already. 
Next : i need for the called service to gen hold of My custom identity object (the one that derives from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.Identityuser)

Thanks in advance 
Frederik

Comment: why do you want to use WCF? If you're using asp.net identity that means you use the newest version of VS and c# so why don't you just use Web API, which is very simple to use.

Comment: I'm having a real hard time keeping up with new MS' technologies and choosing the right one. In my scenario I've made a WPF client which calls the service. Can you tell me the pros and cons of choosing either?

Comment: Please check [Authentication and Authorization with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 for WCF Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802435/Authentication-and-Authorization-with-ASP-NET-Iden)

Answer (score -1):

If you start project from scratch you might as well just use Web API instead. It's just much easier and more straightforward to use when it comes to ASP.NET Identity. If you only need to use HTTP protocol for your REST-ful web services, then Web API is for you.

So to answer your question, just create a new Web API project and make sure you select User Authentication in Visual Studio 2013 and it'll create the authentication code using ASP.NET Identity as a set of web services that you can just use as an example or copy most of it to your project (it will include lots of stuff like login, logoff, change password, register etc).

You can find a lot of articles on the differences between WCF and Web API, for example [this one](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/JI2X050413-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-API-and-WCF-REST-and-Web-Service.html)